# Some events not shown in month view- fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using fullcalendar v5 to draw events in month view. Events are sorted based on 'eventType'.

day max events is set to '3'.

The problem is some days in a month are not showing any events (or less than the dayMaxEvents, notice April 1 in screenshot), and shows +more.

I tried to figure out why this is happening, and I think it's because these  events start on a previous day and this day drew '3' events only (based on sorting), leaving these extending till a certain day hidden.

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [CustomViewPlugin],
    locale: 'en',
    contentHeight: 1000,
    views: {
        year: {
            type: 'year',
            dayMaxEventRows: 3,
            duration: { years: 1 },
            titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit' }
        },

        week: {
            contentHeight: 650,
            dayMaxEvents: 10,
            dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' }
        },

        dayGridMonth: {
            contentHeight: 1270,
            dayMaxEvents: 3,
            dayHeaderFormat: { weekday: 'long' }
        },


    },

    initialView: 'year',
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    eventClick: function (info) {

        let event = info.event;
        showEventDetails(event.id);
        

    },
   
     events:
        [
            // Add your events here
            {
                title: 'Event 1',
                start: '2022-02-26',
                end: '2022-04-01',
                eventType: "Tier 1"
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 2',
                start: '2022-02-26',
                end: '2022-04-01',
                eventType: "Tier 1"
            },
            {
                title: 'Event 3',
                start: '2022-02-26',
                end: '2022-04-01',
                eventType: "Tier 1"
        },
        {
            title: 'Event 4',
            start: '2022-02-26',
            end: '2022-04-26',
            eventType: 'Tier 2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event 5',
            start: '2022-03-26',
            end: '2022-04-26',
            eventType: 'Tier 2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event 6',
            start: '2022-03-26',
            end: '2022-04-26',
            eventType: 'Tier 2'
            },
        {
            title: 'Event 7',
            start: '2022-03-26',
            end: '2022-04-26',
            eventType: 'Tier 2'
        },
        {
            title: 'Event 8',
            start: '2022-03-26',
            end: '2022-04-26',
            eventType: 'Tier 2'
        }
       
        ],

    eventOrder: "eventType",
    eventContent: function (info) {
        //event content here
    },

    fixedWeekCount: false,
    showNonCurrentDates: true

})
```

I want a way to always draw events up to dayMaxEvents even the day isn't the start day.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some relevant event JSON so we can try to reproduce the problem. Right now you have a theory, but we have no easy way of knowing that theory is true or not.

Comment: Also, please state the version of fullCalendar you're using

Comment: That isn't going to be enough event data, or with the right date ranges, to reproduce your problem is it? You're talking about events which cross multiple days, and with multiple events on one day. Those generic examples don't cover the scenario in your screenshot. Also I don't know why you removed the screenshot, it was very helpful for illustrating the issue.

Comment: @ADyson I edited the image and code, please check now, let me know if you can help. I know if I'm to draw them in April 1st, it will seem like events start on that day, but we have a requirement to style these events to indicate they start on an earlier date.

Comment: Thanks. Just to check - which version of fullCalendar are you using? Then I can ensure I reproduce the issue using the same version

Comment: thanks @ADyson, it's mentioned in the question I was using v5. I believe I could solve it by just updating fullcalendar to latest version.

Comment: Sorry I should have seen that, I was looking for the tags on the question...I've added a tag now for you. Glad the upgrade fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Updating fullcalendar from v5 to v6 solved this issue for me, now all days will have events up to dayMaxEvents.

Comment: You need to elaborate your answer. Can you add some details to it?